# How can we be able to generate another element by clicking on a button?

Tags: reactjs

How can we be able to generate another element by clicking on a button? in my case I want to add another input when I click on the button.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button variant="primary">Add another input</Button>
        </Form>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Should the new one belong to any particular form control? Or is it just a textbox?

Comment: You'd use the component's state to track what elements you want to render, and you'd use a button click handler to update that state.  Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';

function App() {
    const [activeInput, setActiveInput] = useState(false)
    const handleClick = () => {
        setActiveInput(!activeInput)
    }
    return (
        <Form>
            <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
                <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            </Form.Group>
            { activeInput && <input type="text" placeholder="type something "/> }
            <Button variant="primary"
            onClick={handleClick}
            >Add another input</Button>
        </Form>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. last request can you make it not a toggle button because when I click again the button the inputs will disappear.

Comment: `setActiveInput(!activeInput)` change to `setActiveInput(true)`